# ¿Como hago en esta consulta en sqlserver?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, sql-server-2017

Buenas me podrian ayudar en esta cosulta en la base de datos northwind:

- Quiero ver un listado que me diga por cliente que productos(nombre) ha comprado, periodo de la compra (fecha de la compra, **ejemplo:** 'mar-96')
- El monto de la compra y que se vea combinaciones de todos contra todos
- Hay que incluir los cliente que no te compraron y que diga que ese cliente compro cero
- Nota incluir todos los clientes por cada mes

Llegue solo hasta esta parte

```
SELECT C.CompanyName,
       P.ProductName,
       o.OrderDate,
       convert(varchar(100),datename(month,(o.OrderDate))) +'/'+ convert(varchar(100),year(o.OrderDate)) [Mes Año],
       (od.Quantity*od.UnitPrice) Total,
       lista.Date
FROM (SELECT DATEADD(month ,number+1,'19951201') [Date]
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE type = 'P'
        AND DATEADD(DAY,number+1,'19960101') < '20001201') lista,Customers C
join Orders O
    on C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
join [Order Details] OD
    on O.OrderID = OD.OrderID
join Products P
    on OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
where O.OrderDate=lista.Date
order by [Mes Año];
```

Muchas gracias igualmente

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que son todos esos campos?  Datos de entrada? datos de salida? tu salida actual? que problemas tiene tu salida actual?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te hizo falta hacer un cross join con productos para tener la combinación de todos los productos con todas las fechas y todos los clientes. El resto es simplemente cambiar los INNER JOIN por LEFT JOIN y agregar la sumatoria.

```
SELECT C.CompanyName,
       P.ProductName,
       CONVERT(CHAR(6),lista.Date) +'/'+ convert(char(4),year(lista.Date)) [Mes Año],
       SUM(ISNULL(od.Quantity*od.UnitPrice, 0)) Total
FROM (SELECT DATEADD(month ,number+1,'19951201') [Date]
        FROM master..spt_values
        WHERE type = 'P'
        AND DATEADD(month,number+1,'19960101') < '20001201') lista
CROSS JOIN Customers        C
CROSS JOIN Products         P 
LEFT JOIN Orders           O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID AND O.OrderDate >= lista.[Date] AND O.OrderDate < DATEADD( month, 1, [Date])
LEFT JOIN [Order Details] OD ON O.OrderID    = OD.OrderID
                            AND OD.ProductID = P.ProductID
GROUP BY  C.CompanyName,
       P.ProductName,
       lista.Date
ORDER BY C.CompanyName,
       P.ProductName,
       lista.Date;
```

Comment: Eres lo máximo amigo muchas gracias en serio 
estaba estancando en este problema
de nuevo muchas gracias

Comment: Al estar usando la base de datos Northwind, asumo que es una forma de estudiar/aprender. Por lo tanto, es importante que comprendas bien la solución y cuales eran los errores que habías cometido. Si no comprendes algo, es mejor que pidas que se aclare.